# The primary reference could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly

Tags: c#

I'm trying to compile a project but I just get errors when I'm trying to build it. I get a couple of errors and a bunch of warnings. I think the warnings and errors is caused by the same thing, DreamSeat. Here's one of the warnings:

```
The primary reference "DreamSeat, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Collections, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "DreamSeat, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Collections, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
```

I also get errors like:

```
The type or namespace name 'DreamSeat' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

All the errors and warnings are similar so I think they are all caused by DreamSeat.

If tried to remove the DreamSeat reference from the .csproj file and got past the warnings but I still get the errors. The program is written in C# and I'm using .NET Framework 4.

Build output: http://pastebin.com/Gng6616g

Comment: Those are .NET 4.5 assemblies, hard to guess how it got borken like that.  Do not build it yourself, use Nuget to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Missing Dll. The references of Dreamseat are used and its looking for the dll, which is missing. Download the dll from the location where you found the source code, and recompile.
Removing references is not a solution.

Comment: There aren't any download for Dreamseat where I downloaded the source from. I downloaded Dreamseat from Github and changed the path in the .csproj file to a correct path but it's still not working.

Comment: What framework you are using? Since its showing its using Dynamic to pick the dll in runtime. You have look for appropriate folder where such dlls needs to be placed, like plugins, lib, modules etc.